# RCurl for json stream. Equivalent of CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER?

Tags: json, r, rcurl

Does RCurl have an option to get streaming json data from a web url ?
The data from the web api keeps adding new json blocks which I need to parse as a stream.
Was lost of the streaming data packages. Didnt get any solution that worked for this case.
(Not a homework!) Any starters ?

Comment: See `httr::write_stream`. (You'll need to get the development version from https://github.com/hadley/httr

Comment: @hadley do you know if there is a package for eventssource Server-Sent Events processing in R ? I need this because the server-side-events are not all json http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/ and stream parsing fails with something like jsonlite::stream_in or httr::write_stream and then converting it to JSON.

Comment: I don't know. You should be able to implement it on top of `write_stream()`, but you will probably need extra code to figure out the start and end of each event.